# Using Git, how to fetch file from local repository?

Tags: git

I'm new to git..I wonder how to fetch older version from the local repository?

For example

First, I initialize git：

```
cd ~/app
git init
git add .
git commit -m "init"
```

Then, I create a file: a.cpp

Then, I update git:

```
git add .
git commit -m "test"
```

Now, my question is, how to recover the "app" folder to the version just after the first commit?

I mean, with what command can I remove the a.cpp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

This will reset your repo one commit behind, which in this case is the first commit.

Answer (score 1):

Since you commited the file, you might want to try

```
git revert HEAD
```

This will revert the last commit by adding a new commit that effectively removes the changes of the last.

You might also want to have a look at http://progit.org/book/ch2-4.html for further reference on how to undo things and working with git.

http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html is also a good source for these things, though a little outdated.